# Why did Ben choose the name "Kylo Ren?"

Tags: star-wars, kylo-ren

There is a question similar to this on the site, but I'm asking with the new information we have from the graphic novel *The Rise of Kylo Ren.*

We know from the movies that Kylo Ren's real name is Ben Solo.  It was a joke for a while when TFA came out that "Kylo Ren" is just a mashup of Skywalker, Solo, and Ben.  However, we never have an explicit explanation as to why he chooses this strange name.  We almost get an answer in The Rise of Kylo Ren.  In this comic, Snoke is stoking Ben's feelings towards the Dark Side, starting with his name.  Ben tells Snoke that he hates his name - he doesn't like being named after some great Jedi he never met, and he doesn't like having his smuggler father's name.
[image]

Snoke asks Ben what name he would rather take, and Ben pauses.  Snoke reads his mind and approves, and Ben says that it's just something he came up with when he was young.  Snoke says that this name is good, because what we come up with when we are young is our truest self.  It's not explicitly said in this scene, but it's heavily implied that he's talking about the name "Kylo."

In this graphic novel, we see Ben join the Knights of Ren.  It's obvious that this is where "Ren" in his name comes from, just coincidentally sounding a lot like "Ben."  But what about "Kylo?"

Kylo does just sound like a combination of Skywalker and Solo.  It already has a lot of similarities to Solo - a name that Ben is insistent he drops.  It seems like it would make more sense for his "true name" that he came up with as a child to be something more out of left field - not a combination of the names he hates.  But the similarity of Kylo to these other names is never brought up in this graphic novel.

So is "Kylo" just a made up name that coincidentally sounds a lot like Skywalker and Solo?  Or is there more to it?

Comment: Ky+lo here: https://screenrant.com/star-wars-kylo-ren-name-meaning-explained/